# Adding multiple dynamic values with jQuery and outputting results

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my issue is that I am trying to add a bunch of numbers from different boxes that change based on their dropdown, the dropdown bit is all good now I can't add the result :(!

Here is my attempt so far:

```
<select id=discount[0] name=discount[0]>
    <option value=1>option 1</option>
    <option value=2>option 2</option>
</select>
<input class=prices type=text id=postdiscount[0] value=1>

<select id=discount[1] name=discount[1]>
    <option value=1>option 1</option>
    <option value=2>option 2</option>
</select>

<input class=prices type=text id=postdiscount[1] value=2>
    <br>

        total: <div id=netpricestotal></div>
```

and the JS:

```
var netprice = 0;
$("#discount\\[0\\]").change(function () {

    $("#postdiscount\\[0\\]").val(this.value);
    $(".prices").each(function(index, obj){
            netprice += index.value;
    });
    $("#netpricestotal").text(netprice);

});
$("#discount\\[1\\]").change(function () {

    $("#postdiscount\\[1\\]").val(this.value);
    $(".prices").each(function(index, obj){
            netprice += index.value;
    });
    $("#netpricestotal").text(netprice);

});
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/t75ut97f/12/

Thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks guys, managed to fix it myself with Number() (http://jsfiddle.net/t75ut97f/16/) also see the accepted answer for alternative method using parseint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have any element with class `netprices`, you mean `prices` (inputs). Also, you need to `parseInt()` value to convert it into a number.

Move `netprice` var inside `change` event to reset it.

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z8s1au10/).

```
$("#discount\\[0\\]").change(function () {
    var netprice = 0;
    $("#postdiscount\\[0\\]").val(this.value);
    $(".prices").each(function (index, obj) {
        netprice += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#netpricestotal").text(netprice);

});
$("#discount\\[1\\]").change(function () {
    var netprice = 0;
    $("#postdiscount\\[1\\]").val(this.value);
    $(".prices").each(function (index, obj) {
        netprice += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#netpricestotal").text(netprice);
});
```

Comment: Heya thanks, I posted to hastily, I realised I could fix this with "Number()" as well. thanks for the input though (the prices thing was because I changed names and pulled it out a much bigger page im working on) thanks anyway dude :)

Comment: @RobertPounder looks like mine :) except for `Number()`.

Answer (score -2):

I hope [chained jQuery plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) will satisfy you needs